# How to disable subsampling with .NET / GDI+?

Tags: c#, gdi+, jpeg, system.drawing

I am trying to save a JPEG image using the Bitmap class. I noticed that sharp edges were always blury regardless of the quality level that I specify. I figured out that it is due to subsampling of one or more of the channels. How do I disable subsampling when saving the image?

I am currently using this code:

```
EncoderParameters parameters = new EncoderParameters(1);
parameters.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.Quality, 85L);

ImageCodecInfo codec = GetEncoderInfo("image/jpeg");
image.Save(path, codec, parameters);
```

#### NOTE

I know that JPEG is lossy, but that's not the issue here. If I use ImageMagick and save the image with the default options, I get similar results. However, if I specify 1:1:1 subsampling, the blurring disappears.

I do not want to use PNG because I need better compression. If I save the image as BMP and then convert it manually to JPEG, I get excellent results, without blurring. Therefore, the format is not the issue here.

Comment: Why don't you use PNG instead?

Comment: I do not want to use PNG because I need better compression. If I save the image as BMP and then convert it manually to JPEG, I get excellent results, without blurring. Therefore, the format is not the issue here.

Comment: @Antoine: See my latest edit.

Answer (score 4):

JPEG is an image format which uses [lossy compression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossy_compression).  It will cause degredation of your image, no matter what quality setting you choose.

Try using a better format for this, such as .PNG.  Since .PNG files use a lossless compression algorithm, you will not get the artifacts you are seeing.

---

The problem (after reading your edits) is probably due to the fact that GDI+ uses 4:1:1 subsampling for JPG files in it's default Encoder.

I believe you could either install another encoder (not sure how to do this).  Otherwise, I'd recommend using something like MagickNet to handle saving your JPG files.  (It's a .net wrapper for ImageMagick - there are a couple of them out there.)

---

Edit 2: After further looking into this, it looks like you may be able to have some effect on this by tweaking the Encoder [Luminance Table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.encoder.luminancetable.aspx) and [Chrominance Table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.encoder.chrominancetable.aspx).

Comment: I know that JPEG is lossy, but that's not the issue here. If I use ImageMagick and save the image with the default options, I get similar results. However, if I specify 1:1:1 subsampling, the blurring disappears.

Comment: I couldn't find any documentation on LuminanceTable and ChrominanceTable. I also looked for MagickNet, but the web site seems to be dead :(

Comment: @Antoine Aubry: I think the site is just down temporarily.  I couldn't find much info on those, but they are related to jpeg compression and the jpeg encoder, so some searching may help.  For C# usage of ImageMagick, also see: http://sourceforge.net/projects/imagemagickapp/

Comment: @reed-copsey:  Do you know of any documentation on using LuminanceTable and ChrominanceTable with the built in Jpeg codec?  Sadly I can't get the code at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882589.aspx to run without an overflow exception...

Answer (score 2):

I've been trying to figure out how to do this for 2 days, it just blows my mind that M$ wouldn't have included such a simple feature in GDI+.  As an alternative, I implemented my own Bitmap -> Jpeg compressor by writing a small wrapper function around libjpeg.  The critical step is to turn off subsampling like this:

```
struct jpeg_compress_struct cinfo;
...
jpeg_set_defaults(&cinfo);
cinfo.comp_info[0].h_samp_factor = 1;
cinfo.comp_info[0].v_samp_factor = 1;
cinfo.comp_info[1].h_samp_factor = 1;
cinfo.comp_info[1].v_samp_factor = 1;
cinfo.comp_info[2].h_samp_factor = 1;
```

However, this introduced another problem for me: libjpeg doesn't support writing exif tags, which I also need.  Of course GDI+ won't add tags without reencoding the jpg, which completely defeats the purpose.  I looked at libexif, but couldn't get it to compile under visual studio.  If anyone did figure out a way to disable subsampling in GDI+, I'd still love to hear about it...

Answer (score 0):

Did you change SmoothingMode property for your Graphics object? 
In my experimentation, I have found that specifying SmoothingMode value to be anything other than the default blurs the sharp edges. Try it and see if that helps.