# How to deal with color loss on GDI+ Image Resize?

Tags: image, colors, gdi+, resize, loss

I am resizing images with C#/GDI+ using the following routing

```
        bmpOut = new Bitmap(lnNewWidth, lnNewHeight);
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmpOut);
        g.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBilinear;
        g.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, 0, 0, lnNewWidth, lnNewHeight);
        g.DrawImage(loBMP, 0, 0, lnNewWidth, lnNewHeight);
```

and encoding it with the highest quality.

```
System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder qualityEncoder = System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality;
            EncoderParameter myEncoderParameter = new EncoderParameter(qualityEncoder, 100L);
```

However, the images that I get have significant loss of color (I am using JPG images only). The quality is perfect, but color is washed away. Do you have any idea what is goingf on?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Can you post a little bit more code, like the actual saving call for example? Also, can you post example images somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

See [How to disable subsampling with .NET / GDI+?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/745610/how-to-disable-subsampling-with-net-gdi)

The problem is that GDI+'s jpeg encoder doesn't allow chroma subsampling to be disabled, so color information is saved at half resolution. The only workaround may be to use a different encoder, such as ImageMagick which was suggested as an answer to the above.